# Jquery variablename dynamically (compose from string and number)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hello I'm quite desperate searching for a solution for the following problem.

In my script I make an Ajax GET request which returns JSON data.
It succesfully returns the data, after this I loop it and then my problem occurs.

I have the size of the data among with the main data returned and then I make a loop to append each result to my html code.

resp.size = size of resp
for example resp.sp0 = data item

For each step it should then append to the main html code.

$(".magicproducts").append(resp.sp0.d1);

$(".magicproducts").append(resp.sp1.d1);

$(".magicproducts").append(resp.sp2.d1);

etc..

I tried this in my loop but it does not work, it alerts the correct name but does not work when i use it as a variablename.

var name = "resp.sp"+i; 
alert(name);

THE COMPLETE CODE CODE :

```
//SET URL TO FOR AJAX GET

var url = $("#url").val();

//

//START AJAX CALL

$.ajax({ 
type: "GET",
dataType: 'json',
url: "../../inc/myscript.php?url="+url,
success: function(resp){
var datasize = (resp.size);
var i = 0;
do {
var name = "resp.sp"+i; 
alert(name);
$(".magicproducts").append(name.d0);
i++;
}
while (i < datasize+1);
} 
});
```

});

I would appriciate any inputs or answers on how to solve it in the same style as im approaching it now.

Second to this Im wondering if there is no other approach.
Somesort of foreach ? So that it auto loops all the items the resp data contains.

Comment: Could you show the HTML code for magicproducts? Also structure of JSON? @RDBWSF

Comment: JSON return is constructed like this :

$output['sp'.$i]['d0'] = $images[$i];
$output['sp'.$i]['d1'] = $lvl2data[0][5];
$output['sp'.$i]['d2'] = $prices[$i];
$output['sp'.$i]['d3'] = $lvl2data[1][0];
etc..

Comment: HTML code does not matter I believe, I would be happy with an alert(name.d0). Basically what I want is that I loop the data in return resp. I got the size and start a loop, then if the size is for example 10 it should ten times display : resp.sp1.d0 resp.sp2.d1 etc.. If I test it static with alert(resp.sp1.d0) for example its working.

Comment: We need the JSON string itself please. Not the php that generates the JSON string. console.log(JSON.stringify(resp)); would produce that

Comment: You can only append HTML string to certain elements with append. So parameter that you are passing if its HTML string that will get added to html element. Try changing it to var name = "sp"+ i ; and $(".magicproducts").append(resp.name.d0); Also it requires that resp is JSOn object itself. If its a json string then you might need to parse it to JSON and then do above.

Comment: The original result has 34 items i shortened it to 2 (sp0 and sp1)

Comment: http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/2CJE

Comment: Please edit your question to include all code necessary (including the JSON) to reproduce this issue, in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for accessing a JSON object with a string is this:

```
var name = "sp"+i;
resp[name].d0
```

To answer your second question, yes there might be a better way.

Since you are already using jquery, you can `$.each` like so:

```
//SET URL TO FOR AJAX GET

var url = $("#url").val();

//

//START AJAX CALL

$.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "../../inc/myscript.php?url="+url,
    success: function(resp){
        $.each(resp, function(key, value) {
            // key is sp0, sp1, sp2...
            // value is { d0: "magic_product", d1: "more_data", d3: "even more data", etc... }
            $('.magicproducts').append(value.d0);
        });
    } 
});
```

You can also nest the $.each statements to dig into JSON object as far as you want. Let's say your JSON looks like this

```
{ 
    "sp0" : 
    { 
      "d0": { "hello": "world" },
      "d1": { "hello": "mom" } 
    },
    "sp1" : 
    { 
      "d0": { "hello": "dad" },
      "d1": { "hello": "earth" } 
    }
}
```

You can nest your `$.each` statements to loop through each level of the JSON object like so:

```
// first foreach statement to loop through sp0, sp1, etc...
$.each(resp, function(sp, d) {
    // second foreach statement to loop through d0, d1, d2, etc....
    $.each(d, function(i, value) {
        // do something with value
        // ....
    });
});
```

Comment: I accepted your answer because it seems much more effective. Still the question remains how to do it in this way : var i = 0; resp.sp+i+.d0

Comment: I have edited my answer to hopefully address your follow up questions.