# How to write the JsonPath Match?

Tags: json

I got this sample from soapui site and I wanted to know how to write a JsonPath to find out the value for the 3rd short name in the list. Below is a snippet.

```
{
"results": [   {
  "address_components":       [
              {
        "long_name": "1600",
        "short_name": "1600",
        "types": ["street_number"]
     },
              {
        "long_name": "Amphitheatre Parkway",
        "short_name": "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
        "types": ["route"]
     },
              {
        "long_name": "Mountain View",
        "short_name": "Mountain View",
        "types":             [
           "locality",
           "political"
        ]
     },
              {
        "long_name": "Santa Clara County",
        "short_name": "Santa Clara County",
        "types":             [
           "administrative_area_level_2",
           "political"
        ]
     },
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Check the StackOverflow's help on asking questions first, please. Focus on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but also other [help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) would be useful.

Comment: @[Irine Mathew] Accept the answer if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below. res being variable for json object.

```
 res.result[0]["address_components"][2].short_name;
```

Follow below for JSON understanding.

1. Data is in name/value pairs
2. Data is separated by commas
3. Curly braces hold objects
4. Square brackets hold arrays

For looping logic refer to other questions already asked on stackoverflow.

[Jquery variablename dynamically (compose from string and number)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34345544/jquery-variablename-dynamically-compose-from-string-and-number?noredirect=1#comment56432860_34345544)

There will be lot of others too.